# How to increase font size of bar labels in sjPlot package

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

With the `plot_xtab()` function from `sjPlot` package I can plot percentages of `gear` inside of every `cyl` as stacked bar plots:

```
library(sjPlot)

plot_xtab(
  x = mtcars$gear,
  grp = mtcars$cyl,
  margin = "row",
  bar.pos = "stack",
  show.summary = TRUE,
  coord.flip = TRUE
)
```

How can I increase the font size within the plots inside `sjPlot` package?

I know that I can make this plot with `ggplot2` and I know that `sjPlot` uses `ggplot2` under the hood.

I have tried:

```
theme_set(theme_gray(base_size = 20))
```

[image]

Comment: maybe there is a better way, but I think you can save your plot and change the `aes` in that object.

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce the results you are showing above: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN7Qe.png

Comment: You can adjust the default size for the geometry used under the hood like this: `update_geom_defaults('text', list(size = 10))`, *then* call `plot_xtab`.

Comment: @M-- This is interesting, because on my posit cloud I do not have this problem? What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @I_O Thank you very much. I have to test it on my desktop PC. I will give you a note. If it solve my problem your comment should be an answer!

Comment: @TarJae I don't actually think it's related, but I had to load an older version of emmeans (newest version is only compatible with the latest R, so I loaded 1.7.9 from guthub; dependency of sjstats). Check your package versions and try running it in a fresh session.